# text overflow in div not working as expected!

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div style="position:absolute;width:300px;background:yellow">
    <div style="position:relative;height:20px;width:150px;left:0;
                                                 background:red;overflow:visible">
       this text should overflow into the parent div!
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the text to overflow to right side into parent div but it wraps to the next line in the child div.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text, and in-line elements, will normally wrap within the `width` constraints on their parent element as defined in the `width` CSS attribute/declaration.

To *enforce* single-line overflow you can either use a string with no white-space, hyphens, or other breaking characters (basically any non-alphanumeric character). Or you can use the:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

declaration, which forces the text/in-line content into a single line. Though this precludes **any** wrapping, which may become problematic in itself.

Slightly tortured [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yezGF/).

Answer (score 0):

Add the folowing to you relative div

```
whitespace: nowrap
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wmm7t/)

[read this](http://www.1keydata.com/css-tutorial/wrap.php)

Comment: Note that in CSS 3, two additional properties, text-wrap and word-wrap, can be used to control text wrap using CSS.